# Select elements in a list at level 1

Tags: filtering

Here is the code I tried but failed to achieve what I want.

```
list={{{-0.678629, -0.247568}, {-0.555433, -0.21052}}, {{0.606745, \
-0.147331}, {-0.246826, 0.426555}}, {{-0.040916, 
   0.329272}, {-0.261357, -0.164607}}, {{0.883787, 
   0.432163}, {-0.555896, 
   0.690923}}, {{-0.00193167, -0.00326776}, {-0.155916, 
   0.0141922}}, {{0.393342, -0.0505961}, {-0.24225, -0.780803}}, \
{{0.194168, 0.196396}, {0.455803, -0.158632}}, {{-0.416166, 
   0.596879}, {0.0341831, 0.000531598}}, {{0.222941, 
   0.0134066}, {-0.107692, -0.59851}}, {{0.390906, -0.24567}, \
{0.146006, 0.393449}}};
 list//Select[#, (#[[#]][[2]]) >= 0 &] &
```

I want pick an element that every 2nd part of this element at level 1 is greater than 0.

***For instance, `{{-0.416166,  0.596879}, {0.0341831, 0.000531598}}` is suitable because both 0.596879 and 0.000531598 are greater than 0***.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select[And @@ NonNegative[#[[All, 2]]] &] @ list
```

> ```
> {{{0.883787, 0.432163}, {-0.555896, 0.690923}}, 
>  {{-0.416166, 0.596879}, {0.0341831, 0.000531598}}}
> ```

Also

```
Select[NonNegative[Min@#[[All, 2]]] &] @ list

Cases[{{_, _?NonNegative, ___} ..}] @ list

Pick[list, And @@@ NonNegative[list[[All, All, 2]]]]

Pick[list, NonNegative[Min /@ list[[All, All, 2]]]]
```

Comment: How about those elements which equal to 0? In my code above, it's `>=0`.

Comment: @kile, i updated with the correction (`NonNegative` instead of `Positive`).

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you may be after:

```
Select[list, #[[1, 2]] > 0 && #[[2, 2]] > 0 &]
{{{0.883787, 0.432163}, {-0.555896, 0.690923}}, 
 {{-0.416166, 0.596879}, {0.0341831, 0.000531598}}}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But is there a more efficient way to do this?  `#[[1, 2]] > 0 && #[[2, 2]] > 0` is obviously a little long. It's acceptable when  every element has 2 parts but It's extremely bulky when every element has 4 parts.

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
Select[list, AllTrue[Last /* GreaterEqualThan[0]]]
```

> {{{0.883787, 0.432163}, {-0.555896, 0.690923}}, {{-0.416166,  0.596879}, {0.0341831, 0.000531598}}}

Comment: What does `/*` mean? I can't find such a symbol in Wolfram.

Comment: If you type `/*` in the documentation browser, it should highlight the page for `RightComposition` (http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RightComposition.html). See also `Composition` (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html)